# S3 GET failed for Pentaho Kettle

Tags: amazon-s3, pentaho, kettle

Using the `AWS` secret keys, able to see the buckets on `S3`, but not able to fetch files.

`S3 GET failed for '/'` is the error message.

Can someone please help

Complete error message is as below :

```
2016/07/03 10:46:36 - cfgbuilder - Warning: The configuration parameter [org] is not supported by the default configuration builder for scheme: sftp
2016/07/03 21:32:19 - /Users/tcssig/Documents/01.ktr : 01 - Dispatching started for transformation [/Users/tcssig/Documents/01.ktr : 01]
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/user_registration.csv' XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>D062E2DF9C15E4F7</RequestId><HostId>ZiTv/U5JbVo9rDr0CM/bVcZLe7S6BUaOBlXnE899Oqg2rGlzLfB4UpE+AsuMD9H0BowYfse+u68=</HostId></Error>
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - S3 GET failed for '/user_registration.csv'
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - 
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.s3csvinput.S3CsvInput.openNextFile(S3CsvInput.java:306)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.s3csvinput.S3CsvInput.processRow(S3CsvInput.java:103)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/user_registration.csv' XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>D062E2DF9C15E4F7</RequestId><HostId>ZiTv/U5JbVo9rDr0CM/bVcZLe7S6BUaOBlXnE899Oqg2rGlzLfB4UpE+AsuMD9H0BowYfse+u68=</HostId></Error>
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRequest(RestS3Service.java:392)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRestGet(RestS3Service.java:727)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectImpl(RestS3Service.java:1544)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectImpl(RestS3Service.java:1487)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:1994)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:1291)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.s3csvinput.S3CsvInput.openNextFile(S3CsvInput.java:263)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 -  ... 3 more
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - S3 CSV Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - /Users/tcssig/Documents/01.ktr : 01 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2016/07/03 21:32:20 - /Users/tcssig/Documents/01.ktr : 01 - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Comment: Post commands you typed or a screenshot of a result.

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that my AWS cluster is in US Oregon region.

Answer (score 0):

S3 file system has null string as root.

Don't include `/` in the beginning of the object/file path.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the step is unable to connect to the AWS cluster. The solution is in correctly defining the filename. There is a format to do so which is:

`S3://(Access Key):(Secret Key)@S3/(s3_bucket_name)/(absolute_path_to_file)`

If your bucket name is: **BUCKY** and filename is : **ABC.csv**. Then you will have the below format to write:

`S3://S3/BUCKY/ABC.csv`

**Note**: *I haven't used the access key and secret key since it is advisable for security reason to be encrypted. So use it in the space provided in the PDI step and there is no reason to use it in the file format.*

Try giving the filename as in the above format and you will have the solution.

You can read more here: https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/loading-data-to-aws-s3-bucket-pentaho-data-integration/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This error was solved, when I used a paid AWS account from Pentaho in place of my free AWS account.